# Give a width for last td from table on IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with last column from all tables from my project because in last column I have action buttons and I want to be displayed inline unfortunately the tables td have auto width that allow them to be dynamic depending on content from td. How to give a fixed width to last td column. Something like:

```
last td{
min-width: 50px;
max-width: 300px;
width: auto;
}
```

in order to occupy the whole space of last td and to be displayed on one line, i don't know if something line `white-space: nowrap;` for td it is working :|
...and remember , for Ie 8 :)

fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ux4DD/133/

Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now try to `display:inline-block;`

```
.icon1, .icon2, .icon3, .icon4{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ux4DD/137/)**

and you forget  your class `[.]`

**this**

```
    icon2{} 
icon4{}
```

**into this**

```
.icon2 {}

.icon4{}
```